# Unable to figure out problem with BitBlt in win32

Tags: c++, winapi, gdi, hwnd, hbitmap

I am new to windows programming and stuck with legacy code of software and having difficulty in figuring out the cause. The problem at hand is I have a SourceHDC and I am dumping it onto ScreenDC(HWND) and to memory DC. The screenDC behaves strangely in the sense that when application is sending my SourceHDC as black(I dumped it) it doesn't blit any thing black on ScreenDC however on my memoryDC I get black rectangle.

The BitBlt operation  being passed is SRC_COPY

What could be the cause here? How to debug this further. Please advice. Could this be because of alpha. If yes how do i ensure alpha copying in my memoryDC?

Edit

```
//mHDC is ScreenDC

//create compatible DC from mDC
HBITMAP SCREENBITMAP = CreateCompatibleBitmap(mHDC, ScreenWidth, ScreenHeight);
HDC SCREEN = CreateCompatibleDC(mHDC);
SelectObject(SCREEN, SCREENBITMAP);

//Blitting back to back and then dumping
BitBlt(mHDC, realDstRect.left, realDstRect.top, dstWidth, dstHeight, srcDC, realSrcRect.left, realSrcRect.top, SRCCOPY);
BitBlt(SCREEN, realDstRect.left, realDstRect.top, dstWidth, dstHeight, srcDC, realSrcRect.left, realSrcRect.top, SRCCOPY);
```

Attached are the dumps. I noticed one problem the first image (SrcDC) appears black on my screen and here its white

***SrcDC***

[image: Src DC]

***ScreenDC***

[image: ScreenDC]

***MemoryDC***

[image: Memory DC]

Comment: It's been a long time since I've done any Win32 programming but I'm not sure it is advisable to draw directly to the screen DC. Even though this is allowed the screen is a shared resource and other applications and/or Windows itself could also be drawing to the screen DC. So your results are unpredictable.

Comment: I am in need of this because i am moving things to dxgi, which doesn’t allow drawing to hwnd or picking things from hwnd. 

My only hope is to keep a compatible memory hdc in sync with what’s drawn on screen

Comment: @Illuminati sounds like an [XY problem](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/). What are you trying to accomplish in the first place?

Comment: Try **BLACKNESS** and a single **BitBlt**. Also, could you please show a minimal, reproducible sample without private information?

Comment: Just noting that a fully transparent pixel and a fully black pixel have the exact same BGRA value.